# How to detect the position of the system tray with java?

Tags: java, user-interface, system-tray

i have to detect the position of the systemTray with java. I already placed an icon in the tray but don't know if its possible to get the position of that icon?

Best regards

Hemeroc

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. I wanted to display a popup window when right clicking on the tray icon, and no window when clicking on it. (Im still to investigate whether I can use the default popup menu).
So I detected the location of the mouse on the screen when the icon way clicked (A property of the mouse event) and displayed my popup menu there.

Answer (score 0):

No, the API does not offer that functionality. *Why* do you think you need that, anyway What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: I know that there is no API function to do that, thats why I'm asking for a "hack".
There is a bug with transparent icons in linux: if you place a transparent icon in the system tray it will get a gray background. So I'll try to detect the color of the systen tray and set the backgroundcolor of the icon to the system tray color.
Example: http://media.ubuntuusers.de/forum/attachments/1512816/Bildschirmfoto-1.png

Comment: There is also a bug-report about that problem: http://bugs.sun.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6453521 (It's not solved since 2006!)

Comment: @Hemeroc: well, you could use java.awt.Robot do make screenshots and try to find the system tray. But I think it would be much more useful to try and get that bug fixed rather than building a complex workaround. And who says the system tray background is a single color?

Comment: a more actual usage for this would be what i once encountered.. i had a window minimize to the system tray in an animated way. Of course you need to know the location of the system tray for that. I couldn't find a solution so i simply opted for bottom-right of the screen as this would cover 90% of the cases... I would love to see if a solution is found though...